# Thymeleaf doesn't display data using th:each

Tags: spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have tried to display a list of users in H2 database. However, the result is exact scripts that supposed to call the properties of the users in the table BUT NOT the user details in database. There is NO ERROR.

Please help as I don't know what to do after days of researching and re-coding but no success.

The ACTUAL result in the table:

[image: Result]

My view:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
      <td th:text="@{user.id}" scope="row"></td>
      <td th:text="@{user.name}"></td>
      <td th:text="@{user.lastname}"></td>
      <td th:text="@{user.email}"></td>
      <td th:text="@{user.active}"></td>
      <td>
        <a th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${user.id})}" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-user-edit ml-2"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${user.id})}" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-user-times ml-2"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

My model (entity):

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import groovy.transform.builder.Builder;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
@Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
@Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "NAME")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your last name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "ACTIVE")
private int active;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

My UserService:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.GentelellaAlela.Authorization.Entity.User;

public interface UserService {

    public User findUserByEmail(String email) ;
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
    public User saveUser(User user);
    User updateUser(User user);
    User getUserById(int userId);
    void deleteUser(int id);
}
```

My UserServiceImpl:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.GentelellaAlela.Authorization.Configuration.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.GentelellaAlela.Authorization.Entity.Role;
import com.GentelellaAlela.Authorization.Entity.User;
import com.GentelellaAlela.Authorization.Repository.RoleRepository;
import com.GentelellaAlela.Authorization.Repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
    @Override
    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setActive(1);
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> result = (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
        if(result.size() > 0) {
            return result;
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("list")
    public String getAllUsers(Model model) 
    {
        List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();

        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "admin/listUser";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way `<td th:text="${user.id}" scope="row"></td>`